# Designing a site with ads (adsense) for 4K monitors

Tags: web-development, google-adsense, responsive-webdesign

I am in the planning stages of my new website. With the rise of 4K monitors I want to make my site appealing to people who use these larger resolutions.

My site design is based on the responsive 12 column grid system which is used inside of a feed like system. I plan on adding ads from adsense the problem is these ads are usually small relative to the 4k resolution and usually come with raster images. If I make the site use 100% of the width of the monitor then these ads I would assume would look awful. Is there any techniques/tips to incorporate ads into resolutions this large so they look appealing and not out of place.

Comment: This is a design question, not a webmastering question.